# mysql to php to xml shows blank age

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a problem with outputting a list of a requested song title, artist, album, together with the name of the requester and his message in XML.

I tried this but it gives me a blank page:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$query = "SELECT requestlist.host, requestlist.msg, requestlist.name, songlist.ID, songlist.count_requested, songlist.artist, songlist.title,
    songlist.album, songlist.buycd, songlist.date_played,                          count(*) as cnt                         FROM requestlist, songlist
    WHERE   (requestlist.songID = songlist.ID) AND  (requestlist.code<700)    GROUP BY requestlist.msg, songlist.ID, songlist.count_requested,
    songlist.artist, songlist.title, songlist.album, songlist.buycd, songlist.date_played    ORDER BY requestlist.msg DESC, songlist.date_played DESC" ;
$results = mysql_query($query);
echo "<request>\n";

while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo "         <CD>\n";
    echo "<singer>" . $line["artist"] . "</singer>\n";
    echo "<song>" . $line["title"] . "</song>\n";
    echo "<album>". $line["album"] ."</album>\n";
    echo "<name>". $line["name"] ."</name>\n";
    echo  "<shout>" . $line["msg"] . "</shout>\n";
    echo "</CD>\n";   
}
echo "</request>\n";
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: Why do connect to mysql 3 times?

Comment: A blank page is usually a sign that a PHP error occurred, and you have error reporting turned off. To fix: Turn on error reporting in your configuration file, execute the script, and read the error output.

Comment: i just edited my code sorry made a mistake while i was copying the code from my server

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather use `simplexml`, `xmlwriter`or `DOM`to build that XML, and `PDO`for database handling:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); // define $db as PDO in include-file
$stmt->execute();
$requests = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request></request>");

foreach ($requests as $r) {
    $cd = $xml->addChild("CD");
    $cd->addchild("singer", $r['artist']);
    $cd->addChild("song", $r['title']);
    $cd->addChild("album", $r['album']);
    $cd->addChild("name", $r['name']);
    $cd->addChild("shout", $r['msg']);
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

And a small variant with a mapping array:

```
$fields = array(
    'singer' => 'artist',
    'song'   => 'title',
    # ...
);

foreach ($requests as $r) {
    $cd = $xml->addChild("CD");
    foreach ($fields as $name => $column)
    {
        $cd->$name = $r[$column];
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you alias fields in the resultset with the intended names in the output, it's even more easy with `FETCH_ASSOC`. Then the aliasing can move into the SQL query which I think makes sense.

Comment: @michi : +1 for use of PDO and neat and clean XML.

Comment: Also I take back my comment with the aliasing in the query somehow *after* seeing this monster of an SQL string ;) Nice answer, I added a little variation with an alias table in form of an array.

Comment: @hakre "Monster of an SQL String" LOL

Comment: thanks all for the help specially Michi and Hakre i found out that the code that i posted also works but there was something with the requestlist.songID and songlist.ID rows on my MYSQL i am not a developer but try to learn as much as i can because i like devoloping i see i am far behind with php i never used pdo before but it looks great i will read some more tutorials so i can undestand more about it and will try it myself in the future