# PhP not exporting XML in a proper format

Tags: php, xml, rss, mailchimp

Not sure if this is causing my problem but I am trying to setup a rss campaign with Mailchimp. I have several of them setup which work fine.

This time I am trying to create another rss driven campaign, but I am creating the feed myself to get data out of mysql. The only thing is that the XML is exported as plain text and not formatting properly as an xml documnent.

My php code

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

DEFINE ('DB_USER', '********');   
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '*********');   
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '*******************************');   
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '******************************'); 

$rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$rssfeed .= '<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" version="2.0">';
$rssfeed .= '<channel>';
$rssfeed .= '<title>Free Scrabble Dictionary - Word Of The Day</title>';
$rssfeed .= '<link>http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com</link>';
$rssfeed .= '<description>This is an example RSS feed</description>';
$rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
$rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) '.date(Y).' freescrabbledictionary.com</copyright>';

$connection = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
    or die('Could not connect to database');
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)
    or die ('Could not select database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM wordday LEFT JOIN wn_synset ON wordday.synset_id = wn_synset.synset_id LEFT JOIN wn_gloss ON wordday.synset_id = wn_gloss.synset_id ORDER BY wordoftheday.ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);

    if ($ss_type == 'n') {
        $ss_type = 'Noun';
    } elseif ($ss_type == 'v') {
        $ss_type == 'Verb';
    }

    $rssfeed .= '<item>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>'.$word.' - ['.$ss_type.']</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>'.$gloss.'</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/dictionary/word/test/</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", time()) . '</pubDate>';
    $rssfeed .= '</item>';
}

$rssfeed .= '</channel>';
$rssfeed .= '</rss>';

echo $rssfeed;
?>
```

You can see my export at http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/includes/wordoftheday.php

The php script is producing the correct data I need, but when I run a test email from Mailchimp the fields for pulling the title, description and link are showing as blank. In my mailchimp campaign I am listing the fields as

```
*|RSSFEED:TITLE|*
*|RSSFEED:DESCRIPTION|*
*|RSSFEED:LINK|*
```

Can I get my XML to format properly with a .php extension?
Any mailchimp experts out there? :)

Thanks you rock!

Comment: The XML you link to is valid. However, you have a discrepancy in your encodings. Your HTTP header says that the XML is ISO-8859-1, but your XML file states its encoding as UTF-8. Which is it?

Comment: its supposed to be ISO-8859-1, i changed it

Comment: I think you can be more lazy. Let PHP do most of the work for you to create the XML, e.g. take SimpleXML in this case (or XMLWriter in more complex cases). E.g. see here: [mysql to php to xml shows blank age](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16489643/367456) (including PDO tip)