# XML tag wrong format

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to insert a tag like "image id=1" inside a xml feed, and with ids from 1 to 10, but I get wrong XML format error using following code, someone can tell me why?

```
$line .='<images>' . $crlf; 
$i=0;
foreach($images as $img) 
    if ($i < 10) 
    {
        $i +=1;
        $line .='   <image id=<![CDATA['.$i.']]>>' . $crlf; 

        $line .='   <image><![CDATA['.$imageUrl.$img->name.']]></image>' . $crlf;   
    }   
$line .='   </images>   ' . $crlf;
```

I also tried using

```
$line .='   <image id='.$i.'>' . $crlf;
```

and I get xml error......

This is how the feed should look like:

```
<images>
    <image id="1">
        <url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=1&.jpg</url>
        <title>
            <en>FOTO 01</en>
        </title>
    </image>
    <image id="2">
        <url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=2&.jpg</url>
        <title>
            <en>FOTO 02</en>
        </title>
    </image>
```

Comment: the problem is that each feed item can have at maximum 10 images so i need to reduce the foreach statement to 10 images and each image must have a id from 1 to 10 inside a tag like <image id=1> <image id=2> etc.........

Comment: I am pretty sure you have a syntax error. whats the xml error you are getting?

Comment: i get Wrong xml format, i am translating this from portuguese, the portuguese erros is: Erro no processamento de XML: formatação incorreta

Comment: the problem is in this line:     $line .='   <image id=<![CDATA['.$i.']]>>' . $crlf;

Comment: It doesn't look like you're closing that `<image id>` tag.

Comment: What language is this? Most languages (these days) have access to libraries that support manipulating XML data *as* XML, rather than treating it as a string. You'll produce a far better, less *brittle* solution if you start using such code rather than continuing down the route you are currently.

Comment: i know i am not closing it because it does not need to be closed, i just need to have a tag like <image id=1> with no </image id> closing tag

Comment: Damien, this is PHP 5.3, i mean, this is my own version of PHP, i am not a programmer so please excuse my poor language...

Comment: PHP has libraries to create the XML so you don't need to take care of all these problems. A working example is http://stackoverflow.com/q/486757/367456 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16489643/367456  - so don't write XML your own, use a library for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$line .='<images>' . $crlf; 
$i=0;
foreach($images as $img) {
    if ($i < 10) 
    {
        $i +=1;
        $line .= '   <image id="'.$i.'">' . $crlf; 
        $line .= '       <url>'.$imageUrl.$img->url.'</url>' . $crlf;   
        $line .= '       <title><en>'.$imageUrl.$img->title.'</en></title>' . $crlf;   
        $line .= '   </image>' . $crlf;   
    } 
}  
$line .='</images>' . $crlf;
```

Comment: hi, thanks for help, actually the URL part  $imageUrl.$img->name. must be inside <url> tag...

Comment: @ol30cean0 just add it then. It's pretty simple string concatenation...

Comment: yes but i am no programmer my friend..... i am trying here with no luck, will keep trying, thanks..

Comment: @ol30cean0 I added a more precise example for you to understand how to manage it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

XML requires quotation marks (single or double) for all attributes, unlike HTML, which doesn't always require them. Your code looks like it's missing the quotes on the `id` attribute.

If I've got my PHP syntax right, I believe instead of:

```
$line .='   <image id='.$i.'>' . $crlf;
```

you can do:

```
$line .='   <image id=\''.$i.'\'>' . $crlf;
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately with your solution i get a different error, it seems the xml wantd the image tag to be closed, in portuguese the error is: Erro no processamento de XML: tag sem correspondência. Esperada: </image>.

Comment: that means that the xml wants the image tag to be closed...

Comment: Also a difference between HTML and XML: in XML, all tags must be closed. You can close your tag either by doing `<image id='1' />` or `<image id='1'></image>` - both are basically equivalent.

Comment: yes, but i need a line like <image id=1> from 1 to 10 and with no closing tags, this must be possible because other people publish this same feed, so... i just need to understand how to do that... grrrrr

Comment: If that's what you need, then it's not XML. XML has very strict rules about this kind of thing, so there's no getting around it.

Comment: this is how it shoudl be

<images><image id="1"><url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=1&.jpg</url><title><en>FOTO 01</en></title></image><image id="2"><url>http://www.mywebsite/image?id=2&.jpg</url><title><en>FOTO 02</en></title></image>

Comment: Look at your sample, then look at your code. Your code adds the `<image>` tag twice. The first one looks correct (aside from the quotes). Your `$line .='   <image><![CDATA['.$imageUrl.$img->name.']]></image>' . $crlf;` line looks like you need to eliminate the `<image>` from it, since you've already opened `<image>` on the previous line.

Comment: yes I saw it... i changed the second image tag with <url> tag, but still i cant manage to solve the image id=1 thing...