# Error generating XML data

Tags: php, xml, validation, prestashop, cdata

I'm struggling to generate an XML with products retrieved from an online store in a specific XML format to import into a wholesaler site. It's gotten through this URL:

http://movilterra.com/solostocks/

The way I do it is passing the array of products to this XML template that is sent to the output:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' ?>
    <SINCRO_DETAILS>
        <COMPANY></COMPANY>
        <COUNTRY>67</COUNTRY>
        <PRODUCTS>
            <?php 
            foreach ($products as $product):
            ?>
                <PRODUCT>
                    <PRODUCT_ID><?php echo $product['id_product'] ?></PRODUCT_ID>
                    <TITLE><?php echo '<![CDATA[' . $product['product_name'] . ']]' ?></TITLE>
                    <DESCRIPTION><?php echo '<![CDATA[' . $product['description_short'] . ']]' ?></DESCRIPTION>
                    <SECTOR><?php echo $product['sector'] ?></SECTOR>
                    <PRICE><?php echo $product['price'] ?></PRICE>
                    <SHIPPING>48</SHIPPING>
                    <MINIMUM><?php echo $product['minimal_quantity'] ?></MINIMUM>
                    <UNIT_TYPE>9</UNIT_TYPE>
                    <PHOTOS>
                        <PHOTO><?php echo $product['imagen'] ?></PHOTO>
                    </PHOTOS>
                    <KEYWORDS>
                        <?php 
                        $keywords = explode(',', $product['meta_keywords']);
                        foreach ($keywords as $keyword):
                            ?>
                            <KEYWORD><?php echo '<![CDATA[' . $keyword . ']]' ?></KEYWORD>
                            <?php 
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </KEYWORDS>
                </PRODUCT>
            <?php 
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </PRODUCTS>
</SINCRO_DETAILS>
```

Note the **CDATA** blocks, since they might be possibly the root of the problem.
All the strings that are not numeric are being previously filtered through a function which converts them like so:

```
utf8_encode(preg_replace('/[\[\]\!]|CDATA/i', '', strip_tags($str)))
```

I used **utf8_encode()** to prevent errors from tildes and other characters. However I'm still having this error:

**error on line 1247 at column 18: Extra content at the end of the document**

and everytime I reload the URL, the error line changes. If I inspect the code I see that the first TITLE tag (with a CDATA block) seems to swallow every other content.

Could you please help me get this working?

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings to produce XML, use a library that is tested and works for exactly that. There are multiple, an entry level related Q&A on site is: [mysql to php to xml shows blank age](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16488993/367456). It is far easier to handle, less code and more safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a > at the end of each CDATA declaration (no only the title element, all of them), like so :

```
<TITLE><?php echo '<![CDATA[' . $product['product_name'] . ']]>' ?></TITLE>
```

Comment: Perhaps because it's stupid? See the duplicate questions that actually give you some object to create XML, then you don't need to worry about these (and other) problems. As you probably might imagine, you don't need to write XML your own because the problem has been solved already.